# Can we export the content of dojo rich text edior to doc or rtf or pdf files?

Tags: dojo, rich-text-editor

Is there any plugin for dojo editor which can be used to export the content of the editor to doc, rtf or pdf files?

Is it possible at all?

Ref:- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Editor.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any plugin for doing that...
However, for word document you can simply save the html of the editor into a .doc file.
words knows how to deal with HTML.
Only trouble you may have: images